# C# LInq Subquery Issue

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, subquery

I am trying to create a linq query which contains a few subqueries. The query I have created seems to be correct (at least, in syntax) but I get no data sent back and Fiddler is showing an error with this query:

```
        public IQueryable<vGatekeeperApproval> GetGatekeeperApprovals(string UserName)
    {
        SystemsFormsDataContext db = new SystemsFormsDataContext();
        IQueryable<vGatekeeperApproval> query;

        Int32 UserId = GetCurrentUserId(UserName);
        bool IsGatekeeperApprover = IsCurrentUserGKApprover(UserName);
        string strSysApproverEmail = GetSystemsApproverEmail(UserName);

        try
        {
            query = (from s in db.vGatekeeperApprovals
                     join r in db.Requests on s.RequestId equals r.Id
                     where (IsGatekeeperApprover == true || s.OverrideApproverId == UserId)

                     && (
                     (
                     from u in db.Staffs
                     where u.GateKeeperArea == 
                        (from c in db.vGK_DIV_USING_CCs 
                         where c.SEGMENT_CODE ==
                            (from a in db.Attributes
                             where a.AttributeItemId== global_COSTCENTRE && a.FormId==s.Id
                             select a.AttributeValue).FirstOrDefault()
                         select c.PARENT_CODE_L3 
                         ).FirstOrDefault()
                     select u.Id

                     ).ToList().Contains(UserId)

                     )

                     select s
                      );


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            query = (from s in db.vGatekeeperApprovals
                     where s.UserId == 0
                     select s);

            //LogEvent("ERROR!" + ex.Message, ex.Source);
        }

        return query;
    }
```

Any ideas what is causing the problem? Is there a better way to create a subquery in linq?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Shuja

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't used .FirstOrDefault() and .ToList() in the middle of a LINQ-SQL query that executes on the db server.  These operations force object to in-memory.

Try changing the use of .FirstOrDefault() and .ToList() to instead using outer join like:

```
join a in db.Attributes on 
         new {AID=global_COSTCENTRE,s.Id} equals 
         new {AID=a.AttributeItemId,a.FormId} into aouter
from x in aouter.DefaultIfEmpty().Take(1)
```

Then you can test for x == null or not.

Follow this pattern and you can refactor to not even using sub-queries, just outer joins to first row on nothing.

If all your objects were in memory, this would be valid Linq, just not valid Linq-sql.